# SwiftUI TextEditor: console message: [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I am using this EditNotesView, which when I coded it 6 months ago worked fine, but now when I tap in the `TextEditor` the keyboard comes up, but there isn't a cursor in the `TextEditor`.  If I tap again in the `TextEditor` then the cursor appears and I can type a note and save.  I am also getting this error in the console which I assume to be related?

full console error:

```
2021-07-26 17:50:50.679871-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.679947-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.679972-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.679990-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.680006-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.680120-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.680146-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.680165-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.680182-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
2021-07-26 17:50:50.766468-0400 newFitnessApp[510:22218] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x15268e680, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

struct EditNotesView: View {
     @Binding var notes: String
    //@State private var notes: String = "type notes here"
    @Binding var isShowingSheet: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var dataStore: DataStore
     @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
     
     @ObservedObject var workoutDetailViewModel: WorkoutDetailViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    isShowingSheet = false
                }
                .padding([.top, .leading])
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                Spacer()
                Button("Save") {
                    if let unwrappedHKWorkout = workoutDetailViewModel.fullyLoadedWorkout?.hkWorkout {
                        print("NOW WE WILL SAVE")
                        workoutDetailViewModel.updateMetadataAndSaveWorkout(workoutToBeUpdated: unwrappedHKWorkout, updateType: .notes(notes)) { (updatedWorkout) in
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    isShowingSheet = false
                }
                .padding([.top, .trailing])
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
            HStack {
                TextEditor(text: $notes)
                    .font(.body)
                    .if(notes == "type notes here") { $0.foregroundColor(Color.gray) } //This is a hack until TextEditor has a placeholder option
                    .padding()
                    //This is a hack until TextEditor has a placeholder option
                    .onTapGesture {
                    
                        if notes == "type notes here" {
                            self.notes = ""
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
           .onAppear {
                        if let unwrappedNotes =  workoutDetailViewModel.fullyLoadedWorkout?.trackerMetadata.notes {
                            notes = unwrappedNotes
                            
                        } else {
                            notes = "type notes here"
                        }
                    }
    }
}

//This function is used so that TextEditor can take an optional string.  If it gets updated in SwiftUI we can delete it
func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
        set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx I posted the entire view? What else would you need?

Comment: What you have won’t compile since it involves a bunch of custom types. A [mre] would make it possible for someone to experience what you are experiencing to try and help debug it.

Comment: I'm amazed that you can compile this code, especially your "hack" in: ".if(notes == "type notes here") { $0.foregroundColor(Color.gray) }" This does not compile for me and maybe the cause of the error.

Comment: @workingdog .if is a custom view modifier from here: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/conditional-modifiers/ it's so good it should be part of SwiftUI IMO 